# Distributing my TKinter app with pyinstaller doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, executable, windows-11

I have an app with 2 classes:
class called GUI, and a logic class being used by the GUI.
The GUI class app  is being initiated by this 4 lines at the bottom of the class:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    global g
    g = gui()
    g.start()
```

But when I try to do the following command on cmd:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --GUI.py
```

I get the following error:

```
pyinstaller: error: the following arguments are required: scriptname
```

What can I do? I want to have the option to deploy the app to users, where they can just click and launch it after downloading a zip file with the project.
The project consists of 2 classes aforementioned, and an image.

Comment: Try using auto-py-to-exe. It uses pyinstaller but includes a gui to make file selection easier. It helps so that you won't miss any arguments like scriptname

Comment: Why do you have two dashes in front of the script name?  It's not a flag, like the other two parameters are.

Comment: I took it from another answer here, I'm not quite familiar on how to distribute it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just get rid of the two dashes in front of GUI.py, if that is the name of your python file. See [here](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/#:%7E:text=pyinstaller%20your_program.py)